# Проверка max и min js

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть скрипт, который отправляет письмо.

```
    function sendForm(id){
    var form = f('cForm'+id);
    var res = {
        PosName: form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value ,
        posEmail: form.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].value ,
        posText:  form.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value ,
        metod:  form.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].value ,
    };

    var url = 'http://******/*****/' + res.posText + '?format=json';
    $.post("/zxz.php", {url: url}, function(data){
        if(res.posText == data.address) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "scripts/answer.php",
                data: res,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('<p class="inner-w">Please check your email to confirm your withdrawal.</p>');                    
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Invalid address');            
        }
    }, "json");
}

function f (id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Как мне засунуть в него проверку поля

```
PosName: form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
```

На значения min и max, которые указаны в этом поле.

```
 <input class="z"  type="number" size="25" min="22" max="<?php echo $max;?>">
```

Comment: Бить по рукам за такую лапшу! У тебя есть jQuery - зачем же ты так собираешь данные для отправки???

    var res = {
        PosName: form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value ,

Зачем обращаться к элементам формы через form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0] - у них же имена есть.

Форма сериализуется так:

    var res = $(form).serialize();

Если нужно только несколько полей формы:

    var res = $('input[name=PosName], input[name=posEmail]', $(form)).serialize();

Comment: Почему у тебя регистр имен переменных постоянно меняется? PosName,         posEmail, posText, metod.

Comment: Много букв, а ответа на вопрос не вижу. 
Сейчас скрипт работает так как мне нужно, но только нужна проверка min и max. 
Я не просил показать мне ошибки в регистре имен или же в двойных url. 
Задал конкретный вопрос вроде бы...

Comment: Это ещё зачем?

    function f (id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

Чтобы взять элемент с id=abc, нужно сделать вот так: $('#abc')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

- min http://jqueryvalidation.org/min-method/
- max http://jqueryvalidation.org/max-method/
- range (между min и max) http://jqueryvalidation.org/range-method

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#cForm"+id).validate({
      rules: {
          PosName: {
              required: true,
              range: [22, <?php echo $max; ?>]
          }
      }
  });
  </script>

---

Вариант для "без плагинов"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
 * проверка поля PosName на значение
 * @return boolean
 */
function validatePosName() {
    var field = $('input[name=PosName]'),
        min = parseInt(field.attr('min')),
        max = parseInt(field.attr('max')),
        val = field.val()
    if (val<min || val>max) { alert('Некорректное значение в поле "Имя поля по-русски", должно быть между ' + min + ' и ' + max); return false; }
    return true;
}

function sendForm(id) {
    // проверить валидность полей формы
    if (!validatePosName()) return; // если некорректное, то не отправлять форму
    // ... и так далее
}
</script>
```

Comment: Да я сам уже давно сделал.

    var maxc = $('input.Amounts').attr('max');
    var minc = $('input.Amounts').attr('min');

    if(res.PosName < minc || res.PosName > maxc) {
        alert('Incorrectly specified amount');
        return false;
    }

Comment: На рас уж трудились.. =)
А по поводу - "Зачем обращаться к элементам формы через form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0" - затем что на одной странице 8 одинаковых форм - я вот так решил эту проблему. 
Чтобы не писать 10 обработчиков.